# Component issue in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have created few pages in an ionic app but while invoking the page I get the following error `Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for BoxPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?` However i have added the  page details to the `app.component.ts` as `import { BoxPage } from '../pages/box/box';` but still the issue persists. I have implemented some pages like home,product details and cart etc but any newly created pages show the error similar issue persists for few other newly created pages too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error says:

> Error: No component factory found for BoxPage. Did you add it to
>   @NgModule.entryComponents?

You need to add that page (component) to the `@NgModule` of your `app.module.ts` file. You can find more info in [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/#no-component-factory-found-for-):

> No component factory found for...
>
> This error happens when you are trying
>   to use a component, provider pipe or directive that has not been
>   imported and added to your `ngModule`. Whenever you add a new component,
>   provider, pipe or directive to your app, you must add it to the
>   `ngModule` in the `src/app/app.module.ts` file for Angular to be able to
>   use it. To fix this error you can import the offending component,
>   provider, pipe or directive into the `app.module` file and then if it is
>   a provider add it to the providers array and **for a component, pipe or
>   directive add it to both the declarations array and entryComponents
>   array.**

So in this case, you'd need to add it to both, the `entryComponents` and `declarations` arrays:

```
import { BoxPage } from 'the/path/to/the/file';
// ...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // ...
        BoxPage // <- Here!
    ],
    imports: [
        // ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        // ...
        BoxPage // <- and also here!
    ],
    providers: [
        // ...
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This worked fine but one issue still persists that the back button is missing on all the pages that are newly designed am i still missing something ?

Comment: Hmm, that's not related with this at all... could you please add another question on SO with the code of that page, so I can take a look at it?